# Getting error 'Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.'

Tags: android, gradle

Information:Gradle: Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug, :app:assembleDebugUnitTest]
Information:12-07-2017 10:25 - Compilation completed with 34 errors and 0 warnings in 9s 703ms

Error:Gradle: trouble processing "javax/xml/XMLConstants.class":

Error:Gradle: Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)

Error:Gradle: when not building a core library.

Error:Gradle: This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file

Error:Gradle: in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as

Error:Gradle: Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a

Error:Gradle: core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's

Error:Gradle: going on.

Error:Gradle: However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core

Error:Gradle: namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,

Error:Gradle: from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most

Error:Gradle: assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the

Error:Gradle: compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.

Error:Gradle: It is also often of questionable legality.

Error:Gradle: If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only

Error:Gradle: appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine

Error:Gradle: distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use

Error:Gradle: the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.

Error:Gradle: If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact

Error:Gradle: building an application, then be forewarned that your application

Error:Gradle: will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be

Error:Gradle: prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your

Error:Gradle: application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating

Error:Gradle: system. You will be to blame for this problem.

Error:Gradle: If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a

Error:Gradle: core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to

Error:Gradle: repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into

Error:Gradle: your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in

Error:Gradle: conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help

Error:Gradle: you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then

Error:Gradle: that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately

Error:Gradle: lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.

Error:Gradle: 1 error; aborting

Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:

java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:

com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process

---

build.gradle:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26

```
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.rakeshkirola.appiumframework"
    minSdkVersion 24
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',
```

{

```
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'

})

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'

compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client

compile 'io.appium:java-client:4.1.2'

testCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:2.0.0'

testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.9.10'

compile files('libs/httpclient-4.4.1.jar')

compile files('libs/commons-logging-1.2.jar')

compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.4.jar')
```

}

---

Android Studio version : 2.3.3

Comment: Please add a formatted gradle code

Comment: @AmitKumar: Done

Comment: Try to clean your project

Comment: @AmitKumar: I have done that but same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this solved my problem.Try it.

```
android {
...
defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

Comment: :Thanks for the suggestion.But i have tried this earlier as well.Got the same error as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

for enable multidex add **multiDexEnabled true** in your build.greadle (app module) and insert **compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'** in dependencies

```html
android{
  ...
  defaultConfig {
        ...
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries = false
    }

}
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but getting the same error.

Comment: try only compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' might be it will work

Comment: Error:(42, 0) Could not find method dexOptions() for arguments [build_49u93nse19qbhckt8trcffqw4$_run_closure3@2bf1cc3e] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\rakeshkirola\AndroidStudioProjects\AppiumFramework\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>

Answer (score 0):

In your defaultConfig block, add the following options to it.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.rakeshkirola.appiumframework"
    minSdkVersion 24
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```